# Perl: Ignore headers with Text::CSV_XS

Tags: perl, csv, header

I want to ignore headers in my CSV file when using the Perl library Text::CSV_XS.

Is there a better or more proper way to do so than the following:

```
use Text::CSV_XS;

open(my $fh, "<", "file.csv") or die "file.csv: $!"; 
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();

#ignore header
my $row = $csv->getline($fh);

while ($row = $csv->getline($fh)) {  
  #do stuff with the rows... 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would be slightly better:

```
# Skip header
$csv->getline($fh);

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {  
   ...
}
```

It avoids improper scoping, questionable variable reuse and a needless assignment.

---

Alternatively, you could use the following:

```
$csv->column_names( $csv->getline($fh) );

while (my $row = $csv->getline($fh)) {  
   ...
}
```

You're not using the extra information you're passing to `$csv`, so you're doing more work than necessary, but it's self-documenting.